# npm start localhost not working but works on my network

Tags: reactjs, npm-scripts

I created this project using `npx create-react-app` and I'm trying to run a react project using `npm start` ,it doesn't work on the localhost [image]
but it works on my network, the black cube is just me trying out Three.js on React[image: []

here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^7.8.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "drei": "^2.2.21",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-spring": "^9.2.4",
    "react-three-fiber": "^6.0.13",
    "sass": "^1.41.1",
    "three": "^0.132.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also use typescript for the React app, I'm not sure if that's why or not.

here's the terminal output

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view project-name in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.10.106:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

Comment: Can you show your terminal output after running `npm start`?

Comment: Sure, It's the same as if it's working.

Comment: Try navigating the browser to 127.0.0.1:3000 instead

Comment: the same thing happens with this

Comment: this happends on every browser ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I don't think it matters though as long as it uses Chromium.

Comment: I've tried using javascript and the same thing happens